# Telerik Kendo UI Grid: Allow grouping of any one column at a time

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Question is specific to MVC grid control. How to restrict grouping of two or more columns in Kendo Grid? User should be able to drag and group any column but not more than one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind this function to dataBound grid event:

```
function onDataBound(e) {
    var gr = e.sender.dataSource.group();
    if(gr.length > 1){
        gr.shift();
        e.sender.dataSource.fetch();
    }
}
```

Greetings.

Comment: Ideally I would like to avoid two calls to the controller. First call is made with two group columns in the DataSourceRequest object and the second call with one.

Comment: I suggest you to ignore the request when it have more than one group column. It's the simplest way.

Comment: You can use requestStart in dataSource to do the same. This way it will only make one call instead of two.